# What did the Wise Man Say?

Tags: strategy, situation

**An Arab sheik is old and must will his fortune to one of his two sons. He makes a proposition. His two sons will ride their camels in a race, and whichever camel crosses the finish line LAST will win the fortune for its owner. During the race, the two brothers wander aimlessly for days, neither willing to cross the finish line. In desperation, they ask a wise man for advice. He tells them something; then the brothers leap onto the camels and charge toward the finish line. What did the wise man say?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This is a well-known old chestnut: The wise man told the sons to trade camels, and try to get the other son's camel to the finish first.